# Using || to coalesce first non null value

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Here is a function:

```
function() {

    // if on wordpress site decipher if English or Français by using url path
    var lang = '';  
    var wp_path = document.location.pathname.match(/^\/(en|fr)\//)[0];

        if (wp_path == "/en/") {
        lang = "Français";}
        else if (wp_path == "/fr/") {
        lang = "English"; 
        }

    // if on ruby site decipher if English or Français by using querySelector on element
    var ruby_lang = document.querySelector('.menu--primary a[href*="lang="]').textContent.trim();

    // either lang or ruby_lang will be null, assign value to opp_language accordingly
    var opp_language = lang || ruby_lang;

return opp_language;

}
```

In the Chrome JS console this works if I type it line by line:

E.g. on url http://www.example.com/en/

```
var lang = '';  
        var wp_path = document.location.pathname.match(/^\/(en|fr)\//)[0];

            if (wp_path == "/en/") {
            lang = "Français";} // yes NOT English, it's opposite
            else if (wp_path == "/fr/") {
            lang = "English"; 
            }
```

Returns Français as expected.

Then, when I'm on a page without a url path containing either en or fr I know that the variable "ruby_lang" will return either English or Français. I have verified this second part of the function works in the console.

So the 3rd part is presumably the problem. My expectation is that at this point, either lang or ruby_lang are set to a truthy value. So:

```
// either lang or ruby_lang will be null, assign value to opp_language accordingly
        var opp_language = lang || ruby_lang;
```

But instead, whenever I run this function opp_language is undefined.

Does the double bar || syntax behave in a different way than I understand?

Comment: "*opp_language is undefined.*" - very unlikely. Both `lang` and `ruby_lang` are always a string (assuming there was no exception)

Comment: How do you confirm that `lang`/`ruby_lang` are set, and how do you notice that `opp_language` is undefined?

Comment: Cannot reproduce — http://jsbin.com/konulakilo/1/edit?html,console — the only way I get `undefined` for `opp_language" is if one of the other two variables is **not** a truthy value.

Comment: Url if you'd like to see in the console. Landing pages are wordpress (lang variable) and deeper funnel pages are ruby (querySelector variable): http://tinyurl.com/psswacq

Comment: @Bergi I opened the console and pasted in the contents of the function. I can see the variable opp_language is set because it auto populates but is undefined

Comment: If you're on a page without a 'en' or 'fr' in the path then `match` will return `null`, and then accessing `[0]` will throw an exception.

Comment: @DougFirr: `opp_language` is a variable local to that function. If you hit it in the console, you'll get `undefined` from somewhere else (maybe there's a global variable with the same name). Rather put a `console.log` in that function.

Comment: @Bergi but when I check in the console I don't enter it as a function, only as the content of the function starting at "var lang..." and ending at "var opp_language = lang || ruby_lang;". The environment I'm actually working in is Google-Tag-Manager which means a console.log won;t actually log anything to the console. It's a unique environment

Comment: @DougFirr: On the [linked page](https://www.nextissue.ca/en/), your function works flawlessly apart from the syntax error in `.menu--primary a[href*="lang="` (missing `]`) and that there is no element matching `.men--primary`.

Comment: @DougFirr: I guess you're getting an error that you don't see (for some reason). If you enter the body of that function, the `var opp_language` is declared, but because of the exception the initialisation is never executed and it stays `undefined`.

Comment: HI @Bergi when you say "because of the exception"... I've seen that syntax before "try.. catch" but never used it. Should I be doing something like that here?

Comment: @DougFirr: You could try to make sure that the reason for this problem is indeed an exception. I would not recommend to use it as a solution though, rather try not to cause the exception in the first case. It will happen when `.match()` or `.querySelector()` will return `null`, so you should guard specifically against that by using an extra variable for the match result / element, and an `if` statement to check whether something was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working but I don't really understand it. I used try and catch which I have never used before. From what I understood, if the variables could not be set they would just be falsy no?

Anyway, this works:

```
function() {

    // if on wordpress site decipher if English or Français by using url path
    var lang = '';  

  try {
    var wp_path = document.location.pathname.match(/^\/(en|fr)\//)[0];

        if (wp_path == "/en/") {
        lang = "Français";}
        else if (wp_path == "/fr/") {
        lang = "English"; 
        }
  } catch (e) {
    lang = false;
  }


  // if on ruby site decipher if English or Français by using querySelector on element

  try {
  var ruby_lang = document.querySelector('.menu--primary a[href*="lang="]').textContent.trim();
  }
  catch (e) {
    var ruby_lang = false;
  }

    // either lang or ruby_lang will be null, assign value to opp_language accordingly
    var opp_language = lang || ruby_lang;

return opp_language;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If after this line `var opp_language = lang || ruby_lang;` your variable `app_language` is `undefined` this means that both `lang` and `ruby_lang` are evaluating to false. If all values in a "coalesce series" evaluate to false the expression will return the last value in the list.

If you go ahead and type in your console right now `var a = b || c` where `b` and `c` are `undefined` and then log `a` you will see that it is indeed `undefined`.

When an element is not found by `document.querySelector()` your `ruby_language` will be `null` or `undefined`, if you are getting `undefined` then it most probably is.

So basically make sure your variables are initialized and have default values that don't evaluate to false, I guess.

Comment: … or that `lang` is at least falsy, or that the code just never was evaluated and only the variable has been declared.

Comment: If the `querySelector` doesn't find an element, it rather will *throw* on `.textContent` than setting anthing to undefined.

Comment: @Bergi it could be throwing.

Comment: What does "throwing" mean in this context?

Comment: @DougFirr Means that there could be an error in your console you hadn't noticed.